# Best method to Upload images to php server in Android ?

Tags: android, http-post, multipartentity

In my application I need to upload image from Android to php server. I used multipartentity and it worked for me.Can anyone suggest me a method which is faster than this.I need to upload 4 pictures from my application at one time.So it takes a lot of time and I want to reduce this.

Any suggestion please....
Thanks in advance

Comment: use http post post the data to the server. you can google for examples

Comment: The time will be determined based on the connection and the image sizes. Also check this for help with a guide http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/08/16/how-to-upload-multiple-files-in-one-request-along-with-other-string-parameters-in-android/

Comment: No problem, hope I helped